# Entire row and column turning zero for a zero element in matrix

Tags: python

I tried to do the code by following method in colab, but its not working for some unknown reason.

```
  def convertMatrix(matrix):    
    matrixc=matrix
      for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
          if(matrix[i][j] == 0):
            
            for k in range(len(matrixc)):
              matrixc[k][j] = 0
              
            for l in range(len(matrixc[0])):
              matrixc[i][l] = 0
              
            
      return(matrixc) 
  print(convertMatrix([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]))
```

which is basically changing all rows and columns of specified element of copy matrix to zero and return it.

The output turned out to be : [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
when the result should be : [[1,0,1],[0,0,0],[1,0,1]]

Please help with any suggestion on it.

Comment: Please correct the function identations.

Comment: `matrixc = matrix` does not copy the matrix, it just stores a reference to the same object. You are populating the same object throughout your code.

Comment: Your confusion comes from the fact that `matrixc` is not a "copy" of `matrix`. It is the reference to the same matrix.

Comment: "matrixc" references the same object as "matrix". You probably want a deep copy (see module "copy" in standard library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you find your first. "0" you do not stop scanning the matrix for more zeros with i, j: the elements set to "0" on the first match will cause extra "0 crosses" to be added.

If you want to act just on the first "0" found, just stop the scanning once you find it. Otherwise you will have to proceed with two matrices: one source and one target, and look on the source for "0" while operating on the target.

Ah, reading the code: you tried to do that, but the `matrixc = matrix` assignment does not create a new object - both variables reference the same object in memory.

You can use  `copy.deepcopy` to create a new "instance" of  your matrix:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def convertMatrix(matrix):    
    matrixc=deepcopy(matrix)
      for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
          if(matrix[i][j] == 0):
            
            for k in range(len(matrixc)):
              matrixc[k][j] = 0
              
            for l in range(len(matrixc[0])):
              matrixc[i][l] = 0
              
            
      return(matrixc) 
  print(convertMatrix([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]))
```